# Adding a zero before a single digit date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating date field using javascript and there i need to validate the DD/MM/YY

if the user enter the date as 10/06/2012 it will be valid

if the user enter the date as  3/06/2012 means we need to add a zero before the date as 03/06/2012.

my javascript code is

```
$('#date').blur(function () {
            var collector = $('#date').val();
            collector = collector.split("/");
            if (collector[0].length != 2) {
                if (collector[0].length == 1) {
                    //here code for make it as two digit
                }
            }
            else
            {
             alert('Date is not entered properly');
            }
});
```

my html

```
Date: <input type="text" id="date" name="date" />
```

How to do it with javascript

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `collector[0] = "0" + collector[0];` ?

Comment: Why does it need to be '03/06/2012' instead of '3/06/2012'?

Comment: Cool, specification. So, this should've been something you learned on day one of learning strings, so I've no pity on you. Also, your client needs to learn better business processes if they can't handle a non-leading zero. I'll assume this is for manufacturing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
collector[0] = "0" + collector[0];
```

with your code :

```
$('#date').blur(function() {
    var collector = $('#date').val();
    collector = collector.split("/");
    if (collector[0].length != 2) {
        if (collector[0].length == 1) {
            collector[0] = "0" + collector[0];
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('Date is not entered properly');
    }
    // set the val again
    $('#date').val(collector.join('/'));
});​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/qpdVU/)

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to parse the string as a real date and then use [Javascript date formatting](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format), which already provides a way to retain leading zeroes on days and months:

```
var date = Date.parse($('#date').val());
var strDate = date.format('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

*Note: 'd' would not retain leading zeroes but 'dd' will. Likewise for 'm' and 'mm'.*

Comment: add a library for just to pad a value in one field?

Comment: You're right. I like the answer @ManseUK gave better because it is simpler to add in to the existing code